# Proof of idempotence for a function clearing a list but one element

Tags: coq

I'm a beginner and I'm stuck with a proof with Coq about lists of nat.

I have a `list` reg of `nat` and a function clear_regs that change every values to 0 and leave the third value (index 2) unchanged.

I want to show that `forall regs, clear_regs regs = clear_regs (clear_regs regs)`.

I currently have two functions but I don't know if one is better than the other.

(1) The first is defined with an auxiliary recursive function taking an (descending) index and checking if it's the third value. If it's the case it keep its value otherwise it generates a 0.

(2) The second one map `(fun x => 0)` to reg and update the third value with `(nth 2 reg 0)`. I'm using the `let` instruction to keep its value.

I tried things like induction but it doesn't seems to lead the proof to the right path. I don't really know how I should handle the problem.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have defined `clear_reg` with a helper function with a counter to find the *k* th element.  I prove that the helper function is idempotent and use it in a trivial proof for `clear_reg`.

```
Require Import Arith. (* for eq_nat_dec *)

Fixpoint clear_reg_aux (l:list nat) k (i:nat) :=
  match l with
    | nil => nil
    | cons x l' =>
      let x' := if eq_nat_dec i k then x else 0 in
      cons x' (clear_reg_aux l' k (i+1))
  end.
Definition clear_reg l := clear_reg_aux l 2 0.

Lemma cra_idem:
  forall l k n, clear_reg_aux l k n = clear_reg_aux (clear_reg_aux l k n) k n.
Proof.
  induction l.
  - auto.
  - intros k n. simpl. rewrite <- IHl. destruct (eq_nat_dec n k). auto. auto.
Qed.

Lemma clear_reg_idem: forall l, clear_reg l = clear_reg (clear_reg l).
  intros. unfold clear_reg. rewrite <- cra_idem. auto.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will take it as the answer since I need it right now but I will also take in account the answer from ejgallego for a more efficient solution. However, I have a question : why do you use "eq_nat_dec" ? what is it ? (I defined my function in the wrong way, maybe that's why I couldn't prove what I wanted).

Comment: `eq_nat_dec` is essentially a function that is true if `n=k` and false if `n<>k`.  It's not exactly `true` and `false`, but it has type `{n=k}+{n<>k}`.  You will very soon learn about _decidable_ propositions if you continue to study Coq.  Ssreflect uses similar functions but usually map to `bool` instead, but it's very similar.

Answer (score 3):

I have two comments, first, your statement about "register number 2" seems a bit adhoc. Why 2? What happens if the number or registers is 1?

Trying to prove this kind of too-specific lemmas usually complicate proofs in Coq. You would do better trying to prove a more general lemma, such as "for a n-register machine, setting the k < n register twice is idempotent." A proof of that result is in the library as `set_set_nth`. You could combine setting with a "set zero" register operation. I did the proof as you stated it you can compare how the arbitrary 2 complicates size reasoning here:

```
From mathcomp
Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrfun eqtype ssrnat seq.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Implicit Type (reg : seq nat).

(* You could also use take/drop to perform surgery *)
Definition clear_regs reg :=
  set_nth 0 (nseq (size reg) 0) 2 (nth 0 reg 2).

Definition idem A (f : A -> A) := forall x, f (f x) = f x.

Lemma clear_regs_idem : idem clear_regs.
Proof.
(* We reduce equality of lists to equality of their elements, `eq_from_nth` *)
move=> reg; apply: (@eq_from_nth _ 0).
  by rewrite !size_set_nth !size_nseq maxnA maxnn.

(* Now we need to use the fact that nth (set s x) = x, plus a bit of case reasoning *)
move=> i i_sz; rewrite !nth_set_nth /=; case: eqP => [//|].
by rewrite !nth_nseq; case: ifP; case: ifP.
Qed.
```

Note that the proof is induction-free as all the needed induction is encapsulated in the higher-level seq lemmas! I guess you may have had a hard time doing a single induction to prove this lemma as you would likely need to setup a quite complicated induction hypothesis. Thus, it is better to compose several smaller ones.

A different and likely better approach is to use a stronger representation for your registers. In particular, I've chosen to use a nice datatype mathcomp has which is called "finitely supported functions", that is, a map from a finite datatype. The, we represent n registers by a map `'I_n.+1 -> nat` where `'I_n` is the type of natural numbers less than n. Even in your adhoc case, you can see that it works quite well:

```
From mathcomp
Require Import choice fintype finfun.

Section Regs.

Variable k : nat.
Definition reg := {ffun 'I_k.+1 -> nat}.

Implicit Type (r : reg).

Definition clearr r : reg :=
  [ffun idx => if idx == (inord 2) then r (inord 2) else 0].

Lemma clearr_idem : idem clearr.
Proof. by move=> x; apply/ffunP=> j; rewrite !ffunE eqxx. Qed.
```

The `ffunP` lemma is map extensionality: two maps are equal iff they map to the same elements, the rest is routine (eqxx will rewrite `x == x` to `true`.

Here you have runnable code: https://x80.org/collacoq/omemesamoy.coq let me know of any questions.

Regards, E.

Comment: Your proof contains pretty advanced coq stuff. In order to understand it I would have to look up nearly every token. This kind of answer is probably not appropriate for a coq beginner.

Comment: It seems quite advanced for me. I haven't used ssreflect yet.

Comment: @Cryptostasis I feel that If I give a "bad" (or non effective) proof and have the beginner learn that uneffective style, then they would come back later suffering with more complex stuff. IMHO better try to show a effective style from the beginning, even if the learning curve is a bit steeper.

Comment: Hi @Boris, questions are welcome! By the way, if you are going to reason about the kind of structures you mention in the post, the sooner you start using ssreflect the faster you will progress as the theories in the standard library are not so comprehensive. I am talking about an order of magnitude improvement (at least). I'll update my answer to clarify my comment. The rest of the proof is quite straightforward thou.

Comment: @ejgallego Thanks for your answers. I didn't know ssreflect was this important. Maybe I should really try then but I don't fully understand the basics yet. To answer your question, in a context of a project about computer security (details are not really interesting) we have a register called "r_com" (with the arbitrary identifier 2) and we want to show some properties with an abstract compiler clearing every registers but the one called "r_com". Since the identifier is chosen randomly maybe it's better to prove a general lemma.

Comment: @ejgallego Second question : If ssreflect make everything so efficient is there even a point in building proofs with the "classic" Coq ? Should I first fully understand the basics ? (I'm learning with the "Software Foundations" book. But it doesn't seems to provide any resources about ssreflect).

Comment: Indeed I'm almost sure you want a general lemma! Coq is weird in that the most general you can be, the better, but trying to be _too_ general will bite you hard IMO. With regards to ssreflect, it is a specialized library for certain kind of programs and mathematics; it provides many lemmas and structures that are not by default in Coq standard library. I'd compare it to using Boost in C++. For your particular use case it seems to me that it would help quite a bit. I use it exclusively, but YMMV. Also, there's no equivalent of SF using ssreflect, but the documentation is OK.

Comment: Perhaps ssreflect is the future, but I sometimes get the Perl-creeps when looking at the proofs. :-)  I did a traditional style proof which was quite short, and didn't use much automation (semicolons and tacticals  which also can be difficult to grok).

Comment: @larsr , ssreflect is the present for a lot of large formalizations. Of course it is subjective but your solution has an IMHO issue: it introduces a new adhoc definition and theory instead of reusing existing blocks, without solid reasons to do so; this doesn't scale in large or even medium proofs, and had lead to a bad state toward proof reusability in the Coq ecosystem. It doesn't take long for beginners following that path to hit terrible barriers, I get really annoyed when I see a student writing one thousand lines of proofs and losing a few weeks over what is a one line proof in mathcomp

Comment: @ejgallego I understand your point of view but is ssreflect/mathcomp even suited for a beginner ? I can't hide that I feel a bit invovled because that's actually what I'm doing. However, I have to agree that writing so much lines when you can do it with only one line is absurd but maybe every beginner have to start from that, I don't know.

Comment: @ejgallego, you absolutely have a point. I think the way ssreflect structures its proof is really good, and the short proofs it produces is really something to strive for. Thousand line proofs where the author is randomly hacking away for hours and days is not sustainable. Most (all?) of the cool libraries seems to be done in ssreflect these days, so one should absolutely learn it.

Comment: @EngBoris My personal feel is that beginners fare better with mathcomp, as it provides well-tested, ready-made solutions and coding patterns for a lot of tricky issues in Coq, which the beginner has no chance to get right at their first try. You can have a look at Ilya Sergey course (but it is far from comprehensive), also the winter school on math formalization has useful material. The ssreflect mailing list welcomes questions from beginners!

Comment: By Ilya Sergey course do you mean this one http://ilyasergey.net/pnp/pnp.pdf ? By the way, what is "mathcomp" ? Is it different from ssreflect ? Regarding ssreflect if the sooner is the better then I will take a look at it.

Comment: @EngBoris indeed I mean that course. ssreflect is the tactic language, mathcomp is the library built on top of it. In the past, both were known as ssreflect, now the library has grown so large that making a distinction makes sense. People do use the term interchangeably.